# Program that autosaves music position on shutdown?

Tags: audio, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a program that saves the track position and playtime upon shutdown of the Rpi. We're talking a proper shutdown, not unplugging the Rpi unexpectedly.

Imagine the Rpi is an iPod, that when I shutdown the Rpi it remembers where the audio track was, much like the iPod app on an iPhone.

I'm using Raspbian, but I'm willing to switch base OS at this point (not to Android though, I want to maintain OS flexibility).

Comment: You have given me an idea sir. Thankyou. I will ponder my idea and then do nothing with it, because that's how I roll. It's not that I don't like ideas, I find them quite lovely, it's just the doing I don't like. Yeah, that's it. Cheerio.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know of is by using the MySQL database and XBMC(RaspBMC or install XBMC on Raspbian, a lot faster if you install RaspBMC though, as its designed specifically for the pi and is more lightweight) to keep track of your media, this database holds if its been viewed or not, this also works for pausing and restarting of movies (I assume/hope music too) from where they left off.

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=MySQL

Comment: I actually think an auto-resume feature from a media player is what I'm after. I see XMMS does this and I'll have to check it out. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project - One Button Audiobook player that has such functionality. Author shares also his code on his [project site](http://blogs.fsfe.org/clemens/2012/10/30/the-one-button-audiobook-player/).